# If Else Statement and Removing NA's

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I am using an `ifelse` statement to tell the program to categorize months into their respective quarters.  For example January-March (I), April-June (II).....etc.  I use the following `ifelse` statement:

```
eight$quarter<-ifelse(eight$month=="01", eight$quarter=="I", 0)
```

Whenever there is an "01" value in the column titled, "month" for some reason the "quarter" column comes up with the value on NA.  Everything else is fine, as values 02-12 come up zero.  I am curious as to where my coding has gone wrong so I may remove the NA's and replace them with the respective quarter number.

Comment: Is the "01" text and not using the letter O by mistake?

Comment: for a start, you can try `eight$quarter<-ifelse(eight$month=="01","I", 0)` (without the assignment included in your ifelse statement). Of course `0` will be change into character...

Comment: No there is no O is that value, it's "zero-one" per se.  I tried converting the month category to character values, but I end up with the same results.

Comment: @CathG I will try that now.

Comment: @CathG that worked thank you.  What is the difference between your code and mine?  IN other words how does R read the latter code correctly?

Comment: you assigned twice `eight$quarter`

Comment: Try reading `?ifelse` documentation

Comment: The problem was that `eight$quarter=="I"` always returned `FALSE`. He used `==` instead of `=`

Comment: in my code, I say to R : "eight$quarter is : if month is "01" then "I" else 0. I'm not sure what you're telling R

Comment: @LyzandeR right, I didn't see the double `=` !

Comment: @CathG: I suggest you post answer since your comment seems to have addressed the OP's issue.

Comment: @Alex, yes, why not ;-)

Comment: FYI, you can avoid using `ifelse` and do something like `c("0","I")[(eight$month=="01") + 1]`. Also, if you don't care just to get a vector of `1` and `0` (instead of `I` and `0`), you can simply do `(eight$month=="01") + 0`

Comment: @LyzabdeR I thought "==" signifies equal to and "=" means something else

Comment: '==' indeed signifies equal which is a boolean operator, and '=' signifies assign. In the first argument of `ifelse` you check for equality and thus you use the equal sign on the second argument you assign the value 'I' to the variable. '=' is not the same as in mathematics. type help('=') on the console and also help('==')

Comment: It is probably better to understand if I tell you that '==' means 'is it equal?' with the answer being TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
eight$quarter<-ifelse(eight$month=="01", "I", 0)
```

Comment: You can reduce your code a little by using `eight$quarter<-ifelse(eight$month %in% c("01","02","03), "I", 0)` and so on for each quarter.